# Canvas - bullets to mouse point

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

So I'm trying to implement shooting, and what I want to do is take the players x and y and use that as the base point where the projectile derives from and then it basically goes to the point pressed in the canvas. The projectile is deriving from the player, but instead of going to the cursor point it strangely ALWAYS goes right, but will go right+up or right+down depending on which direction was pressed; I've looked on-line and can't seem to find the answer.

Inside my javascript here is the shoot function:

```
function shoot(event){
    bullets[bulletCount] = new Array(4);
    bullets[bulletCount][0] = x;
    bullets[bulletCount][1] = y;
    bullets[bulletCount][2] = window.event.clientX;
    bullets[bulletCount][3] = window.event.clientY;
    bulletCount++;
}
```

In my javascript here is the bullet part in the update method:

```
for(var b = 0; b < bullets.length; b++){
        if(bullets[b][0] < bullets[b][2]) bullets[b][0] += 5;
        if(bullets[b][0] > bullets[b][2]) bullets[b][0] -= 5;
        if(bullets[b][1] < bullets[b][3]) bullets[b][1] += 5;
        if(bullets[b][1] > bullets[b][3]) bullets[b][1] -= 5;
        ctx.fillRect(bullets[b][0],bullets[b][1], 8, 8);
    }
```

and in my index.html page:

```
<canvas id="gameBoard" onClick="shoot(event)" width="500" height="500" tabindex="1"></canvas>
```

EDIT: fixed the problem, for anyone else who suffers this problem inside the shoot function change from what was originally up there to this:

```
function shoot(event){
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    bullets[bulletCount] = new Array(4);
    bullets[bulletCount][0] = x;
    bullets[bulletCount][1] = y;
    bullets[bulletCount][2] = event.clientX - rect.left;
    bullets[bulletCount][3] = event.clientY - rect.top;
    bulletCount++;
}
```

Comment: I recommend using objects with descriptive property names (like `.x`, `.y`, `.destinationX`, `.destinationY`) rather than arrays with magic-number indices. It'll make your code more readable+maintainable with no performance hit (as numerical array indexes are just stored as strings anyway)

Comment: @rvighne how would you imply I do that? I mean I need to keep track of all of the bullets locations so wouldn't I need to use an array? Forgive me if I'm wrong cause I'm new to javascript.

Comment: Use an array to hold all the bullets, as you're doing now, but each *individual* bullet should be an object with four properties, rather than an array with four indexes.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies within these two lines:

```
bullets[bulletCount][2] = window.event.clientX;
bullets[bulletCount][3] = window.event.clientY;
```

It is because that the location you save for the click is not the real location.

You see, `event.clientX/Y` give you the mouse coordinates relative to the **top left corner of the window**, but you only want the coordinates relative to the **top left corner of your canvas element**.

To fix this, first get to know another way to get the mouse coordinates, which is `event.pageX/Y`.

This **will not** give you the coordinates relative to the canvas, however you need this instead of `event.clientX/Y` because it will give you the mouse coordinates relative to the **top left corner of the page, not the window**, which means it **doesn't matter if the user scrolls** somewhere, the coordinates are always true to the page.

So, now that you're using `event.pageX/Y`, how to make it relative to the canvas? Well, we can just take these coordinates and **subtract the top left corner coordinates of the canvas**:

```
bullets[bulletCount][2] = window.event.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
bullets[bulletCount][3] = window.event.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
```

- **Assuming that your canvas element is saved in a variable named** `canvas`

*Hope that solves it :D*

Answer (score 0):

```
    var bullets = []; 
    var bullet_speed = 10;
```

call this in your init() fucntion: which could have your setInterval.

```
    window.addEventListener('click', shoot, false);
```

call this in your draw function:

```
for (var i = 0; i < bullets.length; i++){
    bullets[i].x += bullets[i].xChange;
    bullets[i].y += bullets[i].yChange;
    context.fillStyle ='black';
    context.fillRect(bullets[i].x,bullets[i].y,4,4)
  }
```

---

```
function shoot(event){
    x = event.offsetX
    y = event.offsetY
    d = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Math.abs(player.x-x),2)+Math.pow(Math.abs(player.y-y),2))
    bullet = {
        x : player.x,
        y : player.y,
        xChange : (x-player.x)/(d/bullet_speed),
        yChange : (y-player.y)/(d/bullet_speed),
    }; 
    bullets.push(bullet);
}
```